# Recommended DNS setup for one service running in multiple clusters?

Tags: kubernetes

I was reading through the external-dns proposal here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qaTGTLpPRMqMFZo17J169BsqIfY652Miqc_xXVCYm1Y

This made me wonder about our plan for setting up DNS records for a service running in multiple kubernetes clusters.  So i wanted to solicit feedback from other cluster operators about what they are doing and see if my process is needlessly complicated or lacking.

One of the reasons for our approach is that we plan on running a given service in multiple kubernetes clusters.  For example let's say we have 2 production kubernetes clusters one in us-east-1 and one in us-west-2 and we have deployed a service named 'service' to both of these clusters (today manually in the future through federation).

Here is an image that articulates our DNS setup

[image]

Do people have other approaches for running services that span multiple clusters?   I'm hoping this will dovetail with deploying federated services and would be keen if anyone knows why this won't?

Answer (score 0):

I think some of this could be addressed with GEO features of Route53

https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#what_is_geo_dns